# Good approach for updating the GUI continuously in wxPython using threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

I am working on a GUI app using python v2.7 and wxPython v3.0 on windows 7 OS.
I have to update my GUI continuously which contains lots of panels. Each panels contains a `wx.StaticText`. I have to update these `wx.StaticTexts` continuously. I thought of using `threads`. Also I am using `pubsub` module for communicating with the GUI to update these `wx.StaticTexts`. Every thing works as intended.
I have created a short demo below of my real problem.

**Problem**: In my code below, two threads are created. Both the threads are able to update the GUI using `wx.CallAfter()`. What if I have 100 panels to update? Do I need to create 100 classes for each of the thread which updates a particular panel? I want the threads to work independently of the other threads.
What will possibly be the better approach than this one?

**Code**: Please find the sample code below to play around:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import setupkwargs
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
import time
from threading import Thread
import threading

class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        screenWidth = 500
        screenHeight = 400
        screenSize = (screenWidth,screenHeight)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=screenSize)
        self.locationFont = locationFont = wx.Font(12, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        myPanelA = wx.Panel(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        myPanelA.SetBackgroundColour('#C0FAE0')
        self.myTextA = wx.StaticText(myPanelA, -1, "I have a problem :( ")
        myPanelB = wx.Panel(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        myPanelB.SetBackgroundColour('#C0FAFF')
        self.myTextB = wx.StaticText(myPanelB, -1, "Me too :( ")
        mainSizer.Add(myPanelA, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(myPanelB, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        pub.subscribe(self.updatePanelA, 'Update-panelA')
        pub.subscribe(self.updatePanelB, 'Update-panelB')

    def updatePanelA(self, message):
        self.myTextA.SetLabel(message)

    def updatePanelB(self, message):
        self.myTextB.SetLabel(message)

class threadA(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        ObjA = updateGUI()
        ObjA.methodA()

class threadB(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        ObjB = updateGUI()
        ObjB.methodB()

class updateGUI():
    def methodA(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(3)
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'Update-panelA', message='Problem solved')
    def methodB(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'Update-panelB', message='Mine too')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = GUI(parent=None, id=-1, title="Problem Demo")
    frame.Show()
    threadA()
    threadB()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your private "selfUpdatePanel" to launch its own thread to update its own text field. The code would be easy maintain in this way.

Check following code modified based on your code:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import setupkwargs
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
import time
from threading import Thread
import threading


class selfUpdatePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, mystyle, interval, topic, message):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, style = mystyle)
        pub.subscribe(self.updatePanel, topic)
        self.updateMsg = message
        self.textCtrl = None
        self.interval = interval
        self.topic = topic
        pub.subscribe(self.updatePanel, self.topic)

    def setTextCtrl(self,text):
        self.textCtrl = text

    def updatePanel(self):
        self.textCtrl.SetLabel(self.updateMsg)

    def threadMethod(self):
        while True:
            print "threadMethod"
            time.sleep(self.interval)
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, self.topic)

    def startThread(self):
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.threadMethod)
        self.thread.start()


class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        screenWidth = 500
        screenHeight = 400
        screenSize = (screenWidth,screenHeight)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=screenSize)
        self.locationFont = locationFont = wx.Font(12, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #myPanelA = wx.Panel(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)

        myPanelA = selfUpdatePanel(self, wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, 3, 'Update-panelA', 'Problem solved')
        myPanelA.SetBackgroundColour('#C0FAE0')
        self.myTextA = wx.StaticText(myPanelA, -1, "I have a problem :( ")
        myPanelA.setTextCtrl(self.myTextA)

        #myPanelB = wx.Panel(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        myPanelB = selfUpdatePanel(self, wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, 5, 'Update-panelB', 'Mine too')
        myPanelB.SetBackgroundColour('#C0FAFF')
        self.myTextB = wx.StaticText(myPanelB, -1, "Me too :( ")
        myPanelB.setTextCtrl(self.myTextB)
        mainSizer.Add(myPanelA, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(myPanelB, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

        myPanelB.startThread()
        myPanelA.startThread()


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = GUI(parent=None, id=-1, title="Problem Demo")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```